# How to create different dataframes dynamically from a for loop for storing data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a code like below.

```
ind1=0
    for ind in df2.index: 
                       df3 =df1[df2.iloc[ind1,2:].dropna().tolist()]
                       df3.insert(0,'Col',df2.loc[ind,1])
                       display(df3)
                       ind1=ind1+1
```

Basically for each iteration the data will be stored into `df3`. However i want to dynamically create new DataFrames for each iteration in for loop.

Can anybody help me , how to generate new DataFrames dynamically using the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a list to store dataframes from each loop.

```
df_list = []

ind1=0
for ind in df2.index:
    df3 =df1[df2.iloc[ind1,2:].dropna().tolist()]
    df3.insert(0,'Col',df2.loc[ind,1])
    display(df3)
    df_list.append(df3) ## append this df in list
    ind1=ind1+1
```

Then you can iterate on the list to get individual dataframe:

```
for df in df_list:
    print(df)
```

**You can concat all df's in df_list by doing this simply:**

```
df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Comment: Thank you @Mayank for your immediate response.However will it hold good when i am having more data returned from each dataframe and storing it in a list ?

Comment: We are just creating a list to store multiple dataframes. It has no dependency on the size of the dataframe. So it will hold good.

Comment: Thank You. Can I concatenate all these dataframes from the list using pd.concat ?